# if, empty variables check in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have this code :

```
  def self.add_contact(name, phone, adress, note)

    if name.empty? || phone.empty? || adress.empty?
      puts 'some text'
    else
      Zoznam.new(name, phone, adress, note)
    end

  end
```

But I want another method, no the `empty?` method. because the `empty?` method can be usable only for strings not integers. What is the correct method?

Sorry for my bad English...

Comment: Please explain why you downvote so the questioner can learn how to ask better questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `activesupport` gem which implements `blank?` method. This is probably exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Using `.to_s.empty?` should cover all your cases, which seem to be String, Integer and nil.

```
"".to_s.empty?    # => true
nil.to_s.empty?   # => true
"foo".to_s.empty? # => false
1.to_s.empty?     # => false
```

Answer (score 0):

> But I want another method, not the `empty?` method, because the empty method can be used only for strings and not integers. What is the correct method?

Well depends really on what you consider an integer *empty*. There's no such thing as `empty?` in the `Integer` class because it doesn't make sense. If your variable is of type `Integer` or `Fixnum` there's no way it is empty somehow: it will always contain a value, a number.

What I guess you are looking for is to test the variable `phone` for emptiness in the sense that `nil` might be assigned to it. In that case you can simply use:

```
if name.empty? || phone || adress.empty?
```

or

```
if name.empty? || phone.is_a? Fixnum || adress.empty?
```

if you want to be absolutely sure that `phone` is `Fixnum` (or any other class for that matter).